# How to make textbox slide to the left?

Tags: javascript

### [Here's the JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9SSg3/2/)

Or find below the script:

```
<script>
        $('#box').focus(function()
{
    /*to make this flexible, I'm storing the current width in an attribute*/
    $(this).attr('data-default', $(this).width());
    $(this).animate({ width: 150 }, 'slow');
}).blur(function()
{
    /* lookup the original width */
    var w = $(this).attr('data-default');
    $(this).animate({ width: w }, 'slow');
});
</script>
```

And HTML

```
<input type="text" id="box"  style="width: 100px;" />
```

All I need is to make the textbox grow wider to the left direction instead of to the right..How to do that please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script only changes the width, of the element, it does not grow it to the right. But as the element is aligned to the left, it will expand to the right.

If you want to grow it to the left, you have to put it into a container and align it's children to the right.

See the example:

```
<div style="width: 200px; text-align:right">
   <input type="text" id="box" style="width: 100px;" />
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9SSg3/420/

Comment: It worked..Thanks,, I also tried like this and it worked too. Thansk for the idea. <span style="float:right;"><input type="text" id="box" style="width: 100px;" /></span>